# Android failed to export application (due to google-play-services.jar )

Tags: java, android

I have problem when trying to sign my application in release mode from over two/three days now. I've tried everything which I find as information in internet/stackoverflow and nothing worked for me.

I did not have problem with building debug version and running on device. The only problem I get is only when I try to sign my application on release mode and I get this error message. “Android library project cannot be exported” and I noticed that this happen when I added “google-play-services.jar” to my project  android library for adMob.

Comment: What have you actually tried? How do you sign your application?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Google Play Services jar as dependency, add the Google Play Services library project in your application. Instructions for this can be found at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

Comment: Yes I follow the link to setup the google play services. Everything is working fine on real device (debugging mode) but getting the below error if I want to upload it to emulator and same thing with signing of the apk. I can’t sign it.

Comment: ……… thanks everything is working perfectly after I restarted the eclipse. But the new problem is that my AdView(adMob) is not showing in emulator though I have not test the app on real devices.

Comment: … got  this error in logcat:

<br/>
10-01 23:03:08.606: W/Ads(1002): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x407 dp.
10-01 23:03:08.606: W/Ads(1002): Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 288x375 dp.

Comment: As the error message says, you do not have enough space reserved for the ad. Remove padding or margins (left and right).

Comment: Thanks. Now working, I really appreciate your efforts. More Grease to your elbow

Comment: but i still cant sign the apk... getting this error code "0" after last step of signing the apk. that is to choose where to export the apk to.. i even opened folders but all efort prove abortive.. and i have clean the project many time. help me please. people are expecting the apk this week